# How to customise the dropdown archive widget in Blogger?

Tags: css

I would like some help with customising the archive widget. I've tried the search engines looking for any tutorials but to no avail.

On [my tester blog](http://testerblogiram.blogspot.co.uk) I have installed the default dropdown archive widget. I absolutely dislike the appearance and I'm attempting to alter various elements of it, such as the font, letter-spacing, colours, borders etc however I'm getting nowhere.

There are countless tutorials on how to customise the hierarchy and flat archive widget but nothing for the dropdown menu option. I was told previously that the same coding could be applied to either of the archive widget options but I've found this doesn't work.

The code I'm using to customise the widget is stated below. I've simply added this coding between the tags:

```
#BlogArchive1 ul li { 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    letter-spacing: 0.08em; 
    font-weight: normal !important; 
    color: #171717; 
    border: 0; 
    width: 90%; 
    outline: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #fffffff;
}
#BlogArchive1 a { 
    color: #171717 !important; 
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

The appearance I'm trying to create is very simple with no border and a clear, white background.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, really. You just need to use the below code in order to customize further:

```css
#BlogArchive1 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#BlogArchive1 ul li {
    float: left;
}
#BlogArchive1 ul li a { 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    letter-spacing: 0.08em; 
    font-weight: normal !important; 
    color: #171717; 
    border: 0; 
    width: 90%; 
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fffffff; 
}
#BlogArchive1 ul li a { 
    color: #171717
}
#BlogArchive1 ul li a:focus { 
    color: #333;
}
```